# How to multiply values in a dictionary set

Tags: python-3.x

i have this

```
 flower_bulbs = { 'daffodil': 0.35, 'tulip': 0.33, 'crocus': 0.25, 'hyacinth': 0.75, 'bluebell': 0.50}

 Marrys_order = {'daffodil'*50, 'tulip'*100}

 flower_bulbs['tulip'] = 0.33*1.25
```

how do get marrys_order to have output that isn't daffodil repeated 50 times but has a value of 50 daffodils.

Comment: `'daffodil': 50`, same as how you initialized the `flower_bulbs` dict. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: What do you mean by `but has a value of 50 daffodils` ? Could you show us what you want the resultant `Marrys_order` to look like?

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj he means 50 times of 'daffodils'

Comment: so when we have two different sets of dictionaries, with both containing the same key, does that mean the key 'daffodil', has two different values? or a new value

Answer (score 0):

The code you have output **50 occurrences of string 'daffodil'** and **100 occurrences of string 'tulip'**

```
 Marrys_order = {'daffodil'*50, 'tulip'*100}
```

You need to access the dictionary `flower_bulbs` by key `'daffodil'`

```
Marrys_order = {flower_bulbs['daffodil']*50, flower_bulbs['tulip']*100}
```

Output:

```
{17.5, 33.0}
```

Comment: ah...this is what i want...ty

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
flower_bulbs = { 'daffodil': 0.35, 'tulip': 0.33, 'crocus': 0.25, 'hyacinth': 0.75, 'bluebell': 0.50}
Marrys_order = {flower_bulbs['daffodil']*50, flower_bulbs['tulip']*100}
```

Output :

```
{33.0, 17.5}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python dictionary has key value pairs, in order to access the *value* of a specific key in the dictionary, you need to use `dictionary_name[key_name]`. 
The reason 'daffodils' is repeated 50 times instead of the expected result is because the compiler treats 'daffodils' as a usual string and repeats 50 times (*50). In order to use 'daffofils' as the key and access the value of the key (0.35), you need to use `flower_bulb['daffodil']` like you have accessed `flower_bulbs['tulip']` 
Here's what your code would look like finally.

```
Marrys_order = {flower_bulbs['daffodil']*50, flower_bulbs['tulip']*100}
```

which produces the output

```
{33.0, 17.5}
```